# Windows Phone 7 - Buttons Above Pivot Control

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Used default Windows Pivot App to create pivot application, Wanted to add 2 buttons above Pivot control but they keep on appearing overlapped on pivot, not above. 
E.g. Below code doesn't yield correct result

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

   <Button Name ="btnFav" Content="Favourite" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="157,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" RenderTransformOrigin="1.608,0.329" BorderBrush="#FFD49A48" Foreground="#FF007C00"/>

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Name="objPivot" >


    </controls:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a grid, controls are positioned in lines and columns. If you don't specify a line or a column, the control will be positioned in the first one. So in your case, both the button and the pivot are positioned in the first line and first column, and are therefore overlapping.

Just declare two distinct rows, and put one control in each:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinition>

   <Button Grid.Row="0" Name ="btnFav" Content="Favourite" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="157,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" RenderTransformOrigin="1.608,0.329" BorderBrush="#FFD49A48" Foreground="#FF007C00"/>

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Name="objPivot" Grid.Row="1">

</controls:Pivot>
```

Note that I've declared the first row with an automatic way. This way, it'll be automatically sized to have the same height as its child control (in your case, the button). You can change the value of the Height property according to your needs.